# Don't see Mongocxx

Tags: c++, mongo-cxx-driver

After installing and adding in eclipse linker mongocxx bsoncxx libs,
try compile code

```
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But it fails with error:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF"src/MongoCxx.d" -MT"src/MongoCxx.o" -o "src/MongoCxx.o" "../src

/MongoCxx.cpp"
../src/MongoCxx.cpp:8:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
 #pragma once
         ^
../src/MongoCxx.cpp:13:31: fatal error: mongocxx/client.hpp: No such file or directory
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/MongoCxx.o' failed
 #include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
                           ^
```

Maybe I did something wrong
In official page I follow instruction how install
https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-(New-Driver)

I use eclipse and OS OpenSuse

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code you posted.

Comment: I know its linker. Can't find mongocxx foler, but I add linker

Comment: Why do you think it's the linker?

Comment: It can't find mongocxx, but in pc it installed and I can see it

Comment: it can't find the file `mongocxx/client.hpp`, did you add the path it's in to the include paths? This is a compiler error, not a linker error.

Comment: Yes, I did. 
But it still error

Comment: did you add the path `mongocxx` or the path that contains `mongocxx`. I'm talking about the compiler flag [`-I`](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.htm)

Comment: /usr/local/lib64/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx
/usr/local/lib64/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx

mongocxx
bsoncxx

/usr/local/lib64/lib

Thats I added

Comment: @YaroslvaV but shouldn't either add `/usr/local/lib64/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx` and use `#include <client.hpp>` or add ``/usr/local/lib64/include/mongocxx/v_noabi` and use `#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>`. Or is there another folder called `mongocxx ` inside `/usr/local/lib64/include/mongocxx/v_noabi/mongocxx`?

Comment: @PeterT Noupe, but if I do it, I can see "mongocxx/..." , it has problem too
P.S. maybe we may talk via skype (my nick baksarbed)

Comment: @YaroslvaV if you have a different problem then ask a new question

Comment: The C++11 driver ships a pkgconfig file. If you built the driver correctly, it should be installed with the driver. So, add `$(pkg-config --cflags --libs libmongocxx)` to your compile invocation. If you installed the C++11 driver somewhere that isn't default searched by pkg-config, you may need to appropriately set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in the environment as well.